# How can I stop PHP notices from appearing in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-reporting

I know about `error_reporting(0);`, and `ini_set('display_errors', false);`, but there is a notice appearing in wordpress:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in **/var/www/vhosts/treethink.net/subdomains/parkridge/httpdocs/wp-includes/formatting.php** on line **359**

it *only* appears in wordpress, not in any other pages of the site.

I checked `phpinfo()`, and everything is set so that errors are not displayed. Why does this one still show up?

Here is the line that generates the error:

```
function wp_check_invalid_utf8( $string, $strip = false ) {
    $string = (string) $string;
```

I *did* change some thing in wordpress, to change how the gallery worked. But not this function, and I don't think I changed any calls to this function either. Aside from the notice appearing, everything seems to operate perfectly fine, I just need to get this error to hide.

Comment: Are you sure wp doesn't change the values of error_reporting and display_errors somewhere?

Comment: that's what I was thinking, but the error wasn't there before

Comment: oh, I set the values when I was working on the site, so I could see if there were errors more easily.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to edit your:

```
wp-config.php
```

file and modify the following here:

```
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

otherwise Wordpress overwrites the ALERTS set by PHP.INI

Comment: For this to work for me I had to place these lines at the bottom of wp-config after the config file had called wp-settings.php.

Comment: Important: With current WordPress version this is NOT working anymore. WordPress will overwrite the error_reporting option when you enable WP_DEBUG. This solution is working today (Sep 2015) http://stackoverflow.com/a/27997023/313501

Comment: This solution turns off all the errors not only notices. Eric Henry's solution is better, it allows to keep all errors on, supressing only notices and warnings.

Answer (score 18):

Jan 2015 with latest Wordpress, none of the above works for me.

Creating a php file in mu-plugins folder of Wordpress worked, like :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL &  ~( E_NOTICE | E_USER_NOTICE | E_STRICT | 
E_DEPRECATED | E_USER_DEPRECATED | E_WARNING | E_CORE_WARNING | 
E_USER_WARNING | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_PARSE ));
```

Just name it anything you want ...

i got the answer from here :

https://wycks.wordpress.com/2013/12/05/how-to-remove-error-notices-using-wordpresss-wp_debug/

Comment: This is actually the best solution here as it allows you to use WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY but only hides the PHP notices. The other solutions are either not working or disable all debugging output completely

Comment: Minor change: for me I only need this line: error_reporting(E_ALL &  ~( E_NOTICE));

Comment: created this file, made error in a template, and the page showed the default broken web message, as if WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY weren't set to true.. but they are..:/ when I remove the script, notices and errors show again

Comment: It's still working in 2022!

Answer (score 10):

In wp-config.php add this line:

```
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

That will enable or disable the display of notices and warnings to the page. There is a fuller description of this option, and some related options, here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: this one worked for me - I needed to put it at the top of the wp-config.php though. Thanks (^_^)*

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time these are nothing to worry about (though the plugin/theme developer should know about these so that they may fix them in a future release). PHP warnings and notices are nothing to worry about on a production site most of the time.
Some of these can even be generated because the developer has to keep compatibility with older versions of WordPress as well as older PHP versions.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

with this

```
ini_set('log_errors','On');
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

If you simply **set WP_DEBUG to false** in your **wp-config.php file** you should be fine. These don’t affect your site in any way.

However, the problem is that some times the above does not work.
That can happen most times on cheap shared hosts that force displaying PHP warnings and notices.
In that case, you can replace this line from your wp-config.php file:

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide only errors that comes from this function you can use

```
@function wp_check_invalid_utf8( $string, $strip = false )
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', false);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

---

What I use and it works with the latest WordPress version.