# PHP Notices in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, error-reporting, error-suppression

Hope someone can help with this. I'm getting tons of Notice errors on the frontend of the site I'm busy developing and I want them just put into debug.log.

The following is in the correct spot of wp-config.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

And I've created a mu-plugin with the following in it (as recommended here: [How can I stop PHP notices from appearing in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308379/how-can-i-stop-php-notices-from-appearing-in-wordpress/27997023#27997023))

```
error_reporting(E_ALL &  ~( E_NOTICE | E_USER_NOTICE | E_STRICT | 
E_DEPRECATED | E_USER_DEPRECATED | E_WARNING | E_CORE_WARNING | 
E_USER_WARNING | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_PARSE ));
```

None of the above are working and I'm getting a fair amount of Notices. A lot of them are for undefined offsets or trying to get property of non-object. I will be going through and fixing them but I'd much prefer the errors in error.log than on the front-end.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your PHP version?

Comment: PHP v5.5.26 running on MAMP Pro. Also latest version of WP (4.3.1) and a bunch of custom built plugins and a custom theme.