# Messages popping up on wordpress load

Tags: php, wordpress, load, message

I am trying to hide the following message that keeps on showing when I load any wordpress page:

```
 Force Word Wrapping. For support / comments / whatever, visit the support forums. Version: 1.0.0 Author: Jim Wigginton Author URI: http://www.frostjedi.com/ */ function word_wrap_pass($message) { $wrapAt = 70; $tempText = ''; $finalText = ''; $curCount = $tempCount = 0; $longestAmp = 9; $inTag = false; $ampText = ''; $len = strlen($message); for ($num=0;$num<$len;$num++) { $curChar = $message{$num}; if ($curChar == '<') { for ($snum=0;$snum') { $tempText .= '>'; $inTag = false; } elseif ($inTag) { $tempText .= $curChar; } elseif ($curChar == '&') { for ($snum=0;$snum= $longestAmp || $curChar == ';') { for ($snum=0;$snum= $maxChars) { $finalText .= $tempText . ' '; $tempText = ''; $curCount = 1; } else { $tempText .= $curChar; $curCount++; } // the following code takes care of (unicode) characters prohibiting non-mandatory breaks directly before them. // $curChar isn't a " " or "\n" if ($tempText != '' && $curChar != '') { $tempCount++; } // $curChar is " " or "\n", but $nextChar prohibits wrapping. elseif ( ($curCount == 1 && strstr($wrapProhibitedChars,$curChar) !== false) || ($curCount == 0 && $nextChar != '' && $nextChar != ' ' && $nextChar != "\n" && strstr($wrapProhibitedChars,$nextChar) !== false)) { $tempCount++; } // $curChar and $nextChar aren't both either " " or "\n" elseif (!($curCount == 0 && ($nextChar == ' ' || $nextChar == "\n"))) { $tempCount = 0; } if ($tempCount >= $maxChars && $tempText == '') { $finalText .= ' '; $tempCount = 1; $curCount = 2; } if ($tempText == '' && $curCount > 0) { $finalText .= $curChar; } } add_filter('the_content', 'word_wrap_pass'); add_filter('comment_text', 'word_wrap_pass'); ?>
```

I've tried many different things including what is in this [How can I stop PHP notices from appearing in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308379/how-can-i-stop-php-notices-from-appearing-in-wordpress).

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell with just the code you are showing... we'd need more information to properly answer this.  But, this message appears to be coming from one of your plugins that has been improperly coded.  I would disable all plugins, then enable one at a time until this message shows again.  That will be your faulty plugin.  Permanently disable it/delete it... or contact the author to ask them to fix it if you really need it.

Comment: You are right. I realized that this basically isn't showing any errors, but it is a full .php file being loaded from a plugin. It was missing <?php at the start of the file (had <? instead)).