# Undefined variable: jQuery.min.js

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, undefined

I got this jQuery code from [here - Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moerayan/o3das45q/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $pagination = $('.qpagination');
var $lis = $pagination.find('li:not(#qprev, #qnext)');
$lis.filter(':gt(4)').hide();
$lis.filter(':lt(5)').addClass('active');

var $next = $('#qnext').click(function () {
    var idx = $lis.index($lis.filter('.active:last')) || 0;

    var $toHighlight = $lis.slice(idx + 1, idx + 6);
    if ($toHighlight.length == 0) {
        $prev.show();
        return;
    }

    $next.show();        
    $lis.filter('.active').removeClass('active').hide();
    $toHighlight.show().addClass('active')
});

var $prev = $('#qprev').click(function () {
    var idx = $lis.index($lis.filter('.active:first')) || 0;

    var start = idx < 4 ? 0 : idx - 4;
    var $toHighlight = $lis.slice(start, start + 5);
    if ($toHighlight.length == 0) {
        $prev.hide();
        return;
    }      

    $next.show();
    $lis.filter('.active').removeClass('active').hide();
    $toHighlight.show().addClass('active')
});

}); // close jquery
```

However, when I copied the code and adjusted it according to my need it seems that it doesn't work. I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` error.

What seems to be the issue? & how can I fix it?

**Edit:**
These are the errors I get from Chrome:

> Undefined variable: pagination
>
> Undefined variable: lis
>
> Undefined variable: next
>
> Undefined variable: toHighlight

**Edit#2:**
I got the code to work after loading jQuery 2.2.1 on fiddle but it doesn't work on

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.4.2

in Wordpress, this version is used.
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js?ver=4.4.2

it doesn't work on that one neither, How could I get it to work on ver=4.4.2?

Here is my live website: http://gulf-brokers.com/

Comment: A syntax error is a syntax error. It should also include a line/character number. Start by looking there.

Comment: I copied your code above into the same fiddle with no syntax errors.  I'm using Chrome as well.  Is there a way you can post your HTML code as well?

Comment: Ding - can you check the fiddle? it is not working... I get error by Firefox as welll. SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: Hi Ding, I found the issue, I just edited the post. How could I solve it? any idea?

Comment: It works fine for me:https://jsfiddle.net/o3das45q/2/

Comment: Are you sure you included the jquery libarary?

Comment: Yes, this is the website http://gulf-brokers.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for user3284463
got it working by removing the $ signs from JS variables as the browser confused JS variables with PHP variables and skipped them because I was echoing JS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting PHP errors which is adding certain characters to your script and giving you the `expected expression, got '<'` at `< br`. Looks like you need to fix your PHP errors first or switch off PHP error.

You could fix those errors `Undefined variable: var` by simply defining a initial value for those variables. i.e. `$pagination= "";`

However, I would recommend turning off PHP errors since it should only be enabled at development stage and those errors do not seem to be that critical.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I turned them off but still no luck. any other suggestion? can you check if the right jQuery library loaded on my website? http://gulf-brokers.com

Comment: It looks like those errors are still popping up. Take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308379/how-can-i-stop-php-notices-from-appearing-in-wordpress

Comment: I added error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0); to wp-config the error changed on firefox but still the same on chrome.

Comment: Did you try adding `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` at the top of `wp-config.php`

Comment: @RayanSp I'm using firefox and I too see the errors

Comment: It's pain, since 4 hours I am troubleshooting this. && yes I added that in wp-config.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106829/discussion-between-user3284463-and-rayan-sp).