# WP Job Manager Plugin - [jobs] is not showing

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Good morning everyone!
I’m using the WP job manager plugin, and it has been a life-saver to me. It does exactly what I need to finish this website. The only problem that I’m having with it is that the [jobs] list is not showing on the page that I want (http://vetustup.com/setor-privado/), it keeps loading forever! Have any of you ever had the same experience?
Have a great day!

Comment: Hi, Leonardo, right now your question is off-topic for [so] (please, read the [tour] of each site before asking). As a heads up, it's the kind of error that normally shows up on the browser console, and indeed it's throwing a malformed JSON error. Also, PHP warnings are spilling on your site, not good... see [How can I stop PHP notices from appearing in wordpress?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1308379/1287812) and [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#PHP_Errors.2C_Warnings.2C_and_Notices)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the debug mode of your WordPress site is enabled. You must disable it. Here's how you can disable debug mode:

1. Access the site from any FTP client say Filezilla
2. On the directory where you have WordPress installed there must be a file wp-config.php, open it in a text editor
3. There must be a line:

   `define("WP_DEBUG" , true);`

Make it:

```
define("WP_DEBUG" , false);
```

See also:

- [Debugging in WordPress « WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#PHP_Errors.2C_Warnings.2C_and_Notices)
- [How can I stop PHP notices from appearing in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308379/how-can-i-stop-php-notices-from-appearing-in-wordpress)

Comment: This is not related to the problem, just a side issue.

Comment: No, I'm 100% sure PHP warnings are the real cause of the problem. If you will check the console you'll see this error:

parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

This is because JS is expecting JSON but php warning is messing it.